# How to use the AngularJS ngShow directive to show only if an element is in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

My goal is to, rapidly, have a  tag displaying all the authors associated with a given publication.

Everything works when `$scope.publications.authors` is set to a single value. They do not work when multiple values are stored in an array, as shown below.

I know that the conditional statement for the AngularJS ngShow directive isn't the proper one to use for arrays, but I can't seem to figure out what I actually should use.

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="person in persons" ng-show="person.firstName == publication.authors">{{person.firstName}}</div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.publications = [
{"title": "Research Paper",
 "authors": ["Bill", "George"]};

$scope.persons = [
{"firstName": "Bill",
 "lastName": "Smith"},
{"firstName": "George",
 "lastName": "Jones"},
{"firstName": "Mike",
 "lastName": "Thomas"};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the data structure of `publications`, you need a nested repeater. And you can use a function with current `person` and `publication` passed in to drive the display.

```
<div ng-repeat="publication in publications">{{publication.title}}
    <br/>
    <div ng-repeat="person in people" ng-show="show(person, publication)">{{person.firstName}}</div>
</div>

function ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.publications = [{
        "title": "Research Paper",
            "authors": ["Bill", "George"]
    }];

    $scope.people = [{
        "firstName": "Bill",
            "lastName": "Smith"
    }, {
        "firstName": "George",
            "lastName": "Jones"
    }, {
        "firstName": "Mike",
            "lastName": "Thomas"
    }];

    $scope.show = function (person, publication) {
        return publication.authors.indexOf(person.firstName) >= 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks to all three of you. You were all helpful. sza, you nailed exactly what I had in mind. I owe you a beer or 12.

Answer (score 2):

Make function inside your controller that could check if element exists in `persons` and call it within your `ng-show`. Check fiddle below:

http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/323/

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this would be to use a method in your controller instead of trying to iterate all the data in the DOM.

There are multiple way to do it using a method. If you just want all the name of the authors on 1 line, you could have a method that take the authors and return a string with all the names and refer to this method for the content of your div with this

{{getAuthors(publication.authors}}

You could also have a method that return an array of the names and iterate on it using an ng-repeat with something like this